# DOTA2 keeps forgetting my region

Tags: steam, dota-2, steam-cloud

When ever I launch DOTA2 I have to reset the region, however I didn't have to do this on my laptop?

Any ideas what maybe causing this?

(I don't use any autoexec options)

Comment: Are you launching Steam as an administrator? I'm not sure if this setting is saved locally or on the cloud. Also is your Steam profile based in the proper location as well?

Comment: Nope standard launch

Comment: As DOTA2 is still in closed beta you should probably get in touch with Valve to get a solution or file this as a bug. That's why beta tests are done.

Comment: I dropped them an Email will see where it goes.

Comment: is this problem still occurring?

Comment: Yes, I have also contacted Valve to no reply. At a loss as to what to do about it.

Comment: did u try to open it as an administrator as stated above? starting programs as administrator creates a new config/profile which gets saved. so if you start steam as administrator every time it should not reset the region anymore. if you want you can probably use a script which marks your region automatically at startup. but for now i dont know how to archive this since i didnt find a command yet

Comment: I will give the administrator launch a go. But I believe there is two possibilities for saving the region, a command via auto.cfg or an option that can be set via config.cfg. When setting the region with the console open doesn't seem to show any sign of a command nor does it show any sign of saving to the config... which puzzles me. However will give your idea a go tonight.

Comment: Is Steam cloud enabled for Dota 2? You can also try "Verify Integrity of Game Cache".

Comment: Clouds Enabled, will try Verify.

Comment: Verify did not work. Will wait for future updates. Cheers for all the suggestions :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, same thing happened to me, but I wouldn't think much of it, as it's in closed beta still and isn't perfect yet. I have notified Valve, and they will probably get on that soon, because closed beta is just that- people playing the game, detecting problems, and reporting then to the devs to fix. All in all, there's no fix that us users can implement, but Valve is good about stuff like that, so keep up with their response. (if any)

Comment: True but if you read last few patch notes they claimed to have made efforts to change the save region feature. But good to know I'm not alone on this issue.

Comment: Yes, I do agree that it is strange that this problem still occurred when Valve says they addressed it, but I think that it may just be that the problem was induced by something else for us, something that Valve may not either have found, or just hasn't addressed.

Comment: I can't see any way of fixing this at this current state. So I agree with your answer :).

Answer (score 3):

[May 01, 2013 Patch](http://www.dota2wiki.com/wiki/May_01,_2013_Patch) fixed this problem.